# Variable not in scope (I think), but not sure how to fix it

Tags: java, class, variables, types, scope

What I am doing is just practicing for a test and I thought it was doing just fine, but I am getting, what I think is a scope problem. It says, "teams cannot be resolved to a variable type" and I've tried a few things I thought would fix it, but they didn't work. Here is the code:

import java.util.Scanner;
public class fundamentalsofgame {

```
public String hteam;
public String cteam;

public String teams(String hometeam, String compteam){
    String hteam = hometeam;
    String cteam = compteam;


    return "The teams are " + hteam + " vs " + cteam;

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String hometeam;
    String awayteam = "New England Cheatriots";

    hometeam = scanner.next();

    teams team = new teams(hometeam, awayteam); //error

}

}
```

Comment: `teams` is a method not a constructor. Read tutorials on doc

Comment: Also, capitalize class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`teams` is a method and not your class name instead it is `fundamentalsofgame`. So you need to make object of `fundamentalsofgame` and call `teams` method on it. Change this:

```
teams team = new teams(hometeam, awayteam); //error
```

to

```
fundamentalsofgame obj = new fundamentalsofgame();
fundamentalsofgame.teams(hometeam, awayteam);
```

Comment: Thanks. I get it. It's been a long day.